# It is possible to mock .env file using jest.mock?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

It is possible to mock `.env` file using `jest.mock`? or maybe js works only with regular js models (js files)

my `tests/test.spec.ts`:

```
jest.mock('../.env')

description(...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're able to use `jest.mock()` with any file that you use in the implementation with `require` or `import`.

But since you probably don't `import/require` the `.env` file, you might want to modify some environment variable, where `beforeAll` is really handy.

For example:

```
import func from 'module';

describe('environment dependant function', () =>{ 
  describe('development', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'
    });

    it('should report development', () => {
      expect(func()).toEqual('You are on DEV');
    });
  });

  describe('production', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'
    });

    it('should report development', () => {
      expect(func()).toEqual('You are on PROD');
    });
  });
});
```